# Renaming a topic inside a bag file

Tags: rosbag, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When we record a bag file for example X.bag and it contains the topic data /a_topic

Is there any way to rename the topics name inside the X.bag /a_topic to /b_topic?

Best regards..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9396/renaming-a-topic-inside-a-bag-file/) by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2011-03-12

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is quite old, but there's also this option:

```
rosrun rosbag topic_renamer.py <in topic> <in bag> <out topic> <out bag>
```

Another option is to simply remap the topics when you use rosbag play. For example, if you have the topic /foo inside the bag, you can to this to rename it (when published) into /bar:

```
rosbag play file.bag /foo:=/bar
```

The leading '/' might not be needed.

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2015-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 18

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-07**:
yes. very good! it's very convenient!

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-08-15**:
This info is very good!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if `rosbag filter` can do it, but you should be able to rename the topics using the rosbag API. For an example that reads in data on the `tf` topic and then writes it back out, see [rosbag cookbook](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps). That should be a good example to get you started.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on 2011-03-12**:
Thank you for the response. I also couldn't find anything about the filter. I changed the topic names of openni_camera directly as another approach.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might consider using the tf_remap node that comes with the tf package:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#Nodes

From the wiki:

> **tf_remap**
>
> tf_remap listens to the /tf_old topic
> and republishes transforms on the /tf
> topic. This is mainly used with
> out-of-date bag files that need their
> coordinate frame IDs updated. The
> typical operation for this node is to
> play the bag file with /tf:=/old_tf.
> The tf_remap node is run with a
> ~mappings parameter that describes the
> mapping of frame IDs from old to new.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-13**:
This will only work if @dlmpyr is trying to do stuff with /tf. If it's some other topic, tf_remap probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd use the `rosbag` Python API:

```
from rosbag import Bag
with Bag('Y.bag', 'w') as Y:
    for topic, msg, t in Bag('X.bag'):
        Y.write('/b_topic' if topic == '/a_topic' else topic, msg, t)
```

---

Originally posted by [Tim Field](https://answers.ros.org/users/297/tim-field/) with karma: 191 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-07-19**:
Awesome...saved me a bunch of time finding this. Though I do have one oddity as a result - the bag is now 2x the size. Anyone know why?

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2016-01-23**:
Every time you use rosbag Python API, and I think also rosbag filter, the output bag is uncompressed.
You have to rosbag compress after that. I'd say that's what happened to you.

**Comment by [rubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/36364/rubot/) on 2018-07-25**:
how can you actually replace a topic name by another? how could one change the code for that?

**Comment by [kentam](https://answers.ros.org/users/31544/kentam/) on 2018-10-31**:
Here is my code:

```
from rosbag import Bag
with Bag('Y.bag', 'w') as Y:
for topic, msg, t in Bag('X.bag'):
    if topic == '/a_topic':
        Y.write('/b_topic', msg, t)
    else:
        Y.write(topic, msg, t)
```